# When I get a case of `slicing`?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, object-slicing

Let's look the next code (for example):

```
class A {
    int n;
public:
    int f() const { return n; }
    void set(int i) { n = i; }
};
class B : public A {
public:
    int g() const { return f()+1; }
};
void h(const A& a) {
    a.f();
}
int main() {
    B b;
    A& a = b;
    A* ptrA = new B; 
    h(b);
  delete ptrA;
    return 0;
}
```

Now, Let's look about these lines code:

> A& a = b; // Is there "slicing"? (why?)
>   A* ptrA = new B; // Is there "slicing"? (why?)
>   A a = b; // Is there "slicing"? (why?)

I do not really understand when I want to use any of them, and when, alternatively, you will not be allowed to use one of them. What is really the difference between these lines..

Comment: You can look at [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) for examples. Note that none of the answers there actually explain what is the problem with it (including fgp's answer, even though it claims otherwise).

Comment: kudos for your patience. Actually I dont know what the SO etiquette says about deleting a closed question to repost it, but  I am glad to see that you managed to improve your question considerably and that eventually you got an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Slicing is when you assign a derived object to a base instance. For example:

```
B b;
A a = b;
```

The issue here is that the copy constructor for `A` that is being called only sees the `A` part of `B`, and so will only copy that. This is an issue if your derived class has added additional data or overridden the behaviour of `A`.

When you assign an object to a reference or a pointer there is no slicing. So

```
A &a = b;
```

Is fine, as is:

```
A *a = &b;
```

Comment: The opposite case is slicing as well: `A a; B b; A & ab = b; ab = a;`

Comment: And what is really the meaning of `A &a = b` in this case? all the fields of B class (including these that it's inherit from `A`) will be belongs to `a`?

Comment: @VTT Can you explain your example please?

Comment: @StackUser `A & ab = b;` is just a reference binding, slicing happens at the `ab = a;` because `ab` is a reference to an instance of `B` class.

Comment: @VTT So the type of `ab` is `B` ?

Comment: @StackUser The type of `ab` is `A &` but it references the `A` object that is inside of `B` object instance.

Comment: @VTT I only want to understand the concept. What is the difference between `A a1;` to `A& a2 = b;` (while `B b;`)  (Apart of the types of them) ?

Comment: @StackUser `a1` is an object of `A` class, `a2` is just a reference to an object of `A` class.

Comment: @VTT Ok, and what for example I can doing with `a1` that I can't with `a2` ?

Comment: @VTT In addition, in your example: `ab=a` what is deleted from `a`?

Comment: @StackUser In both cases `a = b;` and `ab = a;` nothing gets deleted. Just not all the fields are copied.

Comment: which fields are not copied in this case `ab=a` ?